# GXT add filter to store

Tags: gwt, filter, filtering, store, gxt

I'm having problems with a relatively simple piece of code.

I'm trying to set a filter for my store items (store associated with a GridView).

```
gridStore.addFilter(new StoreFilter<IncidentDto>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean select(Store<IncidentDto> store, IncidentDto parent, IncidentDto item) {
                        if (item.getDescription().equals("WEEEE-TEST")) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The problem is the store doesn't filter at all.

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to help me out with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13966581/1211000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to enable the filters - this exists so that you can make several filter modifications without actually asking them to act:

```
gridStore.setEnableFilters(true);
```

Sorting doesn't have this as there isn't a concept of turning sorting 'off' - items are sorted to have a new order, then they stay that order. In contrast, filters can be turned back off to restore the items that are no longer visible.

Comment: Thank you! Great, comprehensive answer. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

If you trace the code, you will notice that the filter is not called in onLoad(). You have to manually call filter();

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure where I should be calling filter(); in the sample above...